# Realloc in C and NULL-pointer

Tags: c, realloc

Why does this program not work for every input? (Read in input and print out in reverse order)
Xcode6 generated the Error Message:
hw5(14536,0x7fff7c23f310) malloc: *** error for object 0x100103aa0: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Unfortunately I do not understand this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char *input;
  unsigned long long index;
  input = malloc(1);

  for (index = 0; (input[index] = getchar()) != EOF; index++)
  {
    if (input == NULL)
    {
      free(input);
      printf("Error: Out of memory!\n");
      return 0;
    }
    realloc(input, index + 2);
  }

  for (index = index - 1; index != 0; index--)
  {
    putchar(input[index]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  free(input);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have potential [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code. What if the initial `malloc` fails? Then `input` will be `NULL` but you still dereference it.

Comment: As for your problem, you might want to [read a `realloc` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: Your output is not correct as the index[0] character is missing in output. So you can change second for loop condition to (index >= 0).

Answer (score 3):

realloc() returns a pointer to the new object. I'm using a temporary variable because if realloc() fails to reallocate the memory, a NULL is returned and `input` remains valid.

```
char* temp = realloc(input, index + 2);
if( !temp )
{
    //deal with error ...
}

input = temp ;
```